# Installing latest version of wxwidgets

Tags: command-line, software-installation, gui, c++

I am attempting to install the latest version of wxwidgets via the terminal and followed [these directions](http://codelite.org/LiteEditor/WxWidgets30Binaries#toc2).

However, when I navigated to the folder `/usr/include`, a folder was created called `wx-3.0-unofficial`. Is this the correct folder?

Also, if I wanted to install v3.10.0, would I perform the same commands but replace 3.0 with 3.1?

Basically, are these the correct commands I should use to install wxwidgets or is there a better method?

On the page, the commands are as follows (I skipped the part on installing the IDE):

```
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb http://repos.codelite.org/wx3.0.2/ubuntu/ trusty universe'
apt-get update 
apt-get install libwxbase3.0-0-unofficial \
                libwxbase3.0-dev \
                libwxgtk3.0-0-unofficial \
                libwxgtk3.0-dev \
                wx3.0-headers \
                wx-common \
                libwxbase3.0-dbg \
                libwxgtk3.0-dbg \
                wx3.0-i18n \
                wx3.0-examples \
                wx3.0-doc
```

Then, I followed some directions from the user guide

```
cd /usr/include
ls | grep wx
sudo ln -sv wx-2.8/wx wx
```

I replaced 2.8 with 3.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After waiting for some time, wxwidgets has posted a little tutorial on how to install the latest version. As of this writing, the latest is v3.1.0. The tutorial can be found here:

http://codelite.org/LiteEditor/WxWidgets31Binaries#toc2

> In a terminal, do something like:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-add-repository 'deb http://repos.codelite.org/wx3.1.0/ubuntu/ artful universe'
> ```
>
> For artful, substitute your distribution, such as xenial for ubuntu 16.04.
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get update  
> sudo apt-get install libwxbase3.1-0-unofficial \  
>                      libwxbase3.1-dev \  
>                      libwxgtk3.1-0-unofficial \  
>                      libwxgtk3.1-dev \  
>                      wx3.1-headers \  
>                      wx-common \  
>                      libwxgtk-webview3.1-0-unofficial \  
>                      libwxgtk-webview3.1-dev \  
>                      libwxgtk-media3.1-0-unofficial \  
>                      libwxgtk-media3.1-dev \  
>                      libwxbase3.1-0-unofficial-dbg \  
>                      libwxgtk3.1-0-unofficial-dbg \  
>                      libwxgtk-webview3.1-0-unofficial-dbg \  
>                      libwxgtk-media3.1-0-unofficial-dbg \  
>                      wx3.1-i18n \  
>                      wx3.1-examples
> ```
>
> wx-common and wx3.1-i18n are optional packages and will conflict with the distro's wx2.8 equivalents. That is unlikely to matter too much, but wx-common contains wxrc, so if you use this be aware that there may be differences after upgrading.

Edit:

For a one line command:

```
sudo apt-get install libwxbase3.1-0-unofficial && sudo apt-get install libwxbase3.1-dev && sudo apt-get install libwxgtk3.1-0-unofficial && sudo apt-get install libwxgtk3.1-dev && sudo apt-get install wx3.1-headers && sudo apt-get install wx-common && sudo apt-get install libwxgtk-webview3.1-0-unofficial && sudo apt-get install libwxgtk-webview3.1-dev && sudo apt-get install libwxgtk-media3.1-0-unofficial && sudo apt-get install libwxgtk-media3.1-dev && sudo apt-get install libwxbase3.1-0-unofficial-dbg && sudo apt-get install libwxgtk-webview3.1-0-unofficial-dbg && sudo apt-get install libwxgtk-media3.1-0-unofficial-dbg && sudo apt-get install wx3.1-i18n && sudo apt-get install wx3.1-examples
```

Comment: you forgot to mention the first step from the (broke) GitHub link:
sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys http://repos.codelite.org/CodeLite.asc
Go here: https://gist.github.com/abdulhalim-cu/f3ae4be0b45baabef5623ccdd20ca584
and follow the instructions, but replace "deb" in the second step with sudo apt-add-repository 'http://repos.codelite.org/wx3.1.0/ubuntu/ xenial universe'

Answer (score 2):

Did you look at [wxWidget guide](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Compiling_and_getting_started).

Following the developer guides is always the best way to install something.

Comment: Yes, I did look at this guide; however, it refers to an out dated version. I am looking to install the latest. Unless I replace the 2.8 with 3.1 or 3.0?

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu Bionic some packages don't exist. You might try this

```bsh
sudo apt-get install libwxbase3.0-0v5 libwxbase3.0-dev libwxgtk3.0-0v5 libwxgtk3.0-dev wx3.0-headers wx-common libwxgtk-webview3.0-gtk3-0v5 libwxgtk-webview3.0-gtk3-dev libwxgtk-media3.0-0v5 libwxgtk-media3.0-dev wx3.0-i18n wx3.0-examples
```

Which installs these packages:

- `libwxbase3.0-0v5`
- `libwxbase3.0-dev`
- `libwxgtk3.0-0v5`
- `libwxgtk3.0-dev`
- `wx3.0-headers`
- `wx-common`
- `libwxgtk-webview3.0-gtk3-0v5`
- `libwxgtk-webview3.0-gtk3-dev`
- `libwxgtk-media3.0-0v5`
- `libwxgtk-media3.0-dev`
- `wx3.0-i18n`
- `wx3.0-examples`

Check [these package search results](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libwx&searchon=names) for more information.